# Digits missing points in its accuracy / loss graph

Tags: python, nvidia, digits

[image: Missing points in the accuracy/loss graph]

I am training a convolution net using a custom python layer with augmentation function. Had anyone encountered a similar loss/accuracy graph? Oddly for some epochs the points are not plotted for training loss and validation accuracy. when I checked the output log file, it also didn't print the two measures for many of the epochs. Was wondering if anyone had such issues before and what was causes of the problem in their cases. Thanks!